# Are there any examples of successful multi-decade prevention interventions with pharmaceuticals?

Tags: clinical-study

With many tests able to detect various physical abnormalities, even before symptoms develop (if ever), modern treatments may require individuals to take medications for decades. Are there any examples of such long term interventions in medicine that have been found to be a success as per objective criteria such as lifespan? Failed examples would be interesting too ...

Comment: Hi @Joe. May I ask you what you mean by "various physical abnormalities"? Could you give some examples? Also, what kind of "tests" are you thinking of? Thanks.

Comment: Hypertension is something that kills slowly over many years, hypertension medications are often taken for many years, and there is strong evidence that hypertension medications prolong lifespan. Is that an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, hypertension would be a good example, assuming there are studies spanning longer than 20 years (hypertension was also the possibility I was thinking of, so I'd be interested in hearing about other areas).